# Why do lightbulbs in parallel stay the same brightness when one is removed

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

In my book it reads, "The brightness of C: Increase. (If you remove D) Previously C was receiving only half of the current through the lower branch, now C is receiving all of the current coming out of B."

[image: Circuit]

This makes sense, but everything that I found online says that C would stay the same brightness.

This is how I would try to solve it. The voltage and the resistance do not change, and using I = V/R, the current does not change and therefore the current does not change.

Comment: Are you sure the situations where it was claimed to stay the same brightness also had a third bulb in position "B"?

Comment: The other scenarios only use C and D. Would B affect C and D?

Comment: Of course it will. If you just have the voltage source and C and D, you know the exact voltage across C & D right away. If you include B, then the voltage drop across B affects the voltage across C & D (and depends on the resistance of C & D).

Comment: (A, B, C, and D are identical) I still am a little confused. The path that the current takes can be B --> D or B --> C. Isn't the voltage and resistance equal for both of them?

Comment: Have you learned Kirchoff's Current Law? The current that flows through B has to be split between C and D.  Remove D and then all the current through B must also flow through C.

Comment: Or if you are only just learning resistor combinations, find the equivalent resistance of B, C, & D, vs the just B & C. You should find a different value, so a different total current flows from the battery through the bulbs depending on the configuration.

Comment: Yes, but if you remove B, doesn't it still have to split?

Comment: You mean if you short B? Then it splits, but the voltage source adjusts its current to keep its output voltage fixed.

Comment: If you know KCL and KVL, just assume some value for the bulb resistance and solve the three different circuits. If you don't know those rules yet, that's the next thing you should study.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: if the output impedance of the battery were zero, then removing A would not change the brightness of the other lights.  but the internal battery resistance is not zero, so i imagine that B, C, and D will burn a little bit brighter with A removed.

Comment: *This is how I would try to solve it. The voltage and the resistance do not change...* If you remove a resistor, how can the resistance not change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us suppose  in the above  circuit all the bulbs  are identical having  resistance  r.

In that  situation A  will be brightest  of all the bulbs  and  next  comes  B  and C as well as D will be  lowest  bright .

so  naturally  when  you  remove  either C  or D  the bulb will be brighter  compared to what it was glowing  earlier.

I think  one should  apply the  rule that  the voltage  **V = current x Resistance**

as the bulbs  have identical  resistance  the bulb  A gets the full  voltage of the battery. so its  glowing  brightest getting the max.  current  say IA.

**V = IA.r**  where  V is the battery  voltage.

the **B, C, and D  are  sharing the voltage  in the  lower arm.**

**V = IB .r  + IC.r  = IB .r  + ID.r**

IC and ID are equal as  the current IB is  dividing equally   in C  and D arm.

However **IC +ID = IB**  or  **IC = IB/2**. (Kirchhoff's Law)

that's why I noted above  that **A will be brightest**  getting current  **IA= V/r**

the Bulb B will have current IB = IA- IC  , so a lower glow than A.

and C and D will be equally  glowing but lower than A as well as B.

moreover , when one removes D now  V= IB.r +IC.r    and **IB= IC**

so **IB= IA/2**

and B as well as C  will glow  equally  less than A. and **C will be brighter** than the previous  arrangement of C and D parallel.

*Though its  true that in parallel  bulbs  arrangement  removal of a bulb does  not lead  to any  fluctuation in the other  parallel connected  bulb's  brightness.*

However, in your  present  arrangement the C and D are parallel not to voltage  supply  but  is in series with **B** and sharing the **input  voltage with B**. that's why this seemingly  opposite  fluctuation is being seen.